# System.IO.IOException: Device or resource is busy, Trying to open serial Raspberry Pi serial port (/dev/ttyAMA0)

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I trying to open serial port **/dev/ttyAMA0** using asp.net core 3.0 with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and Raspbian OS, after opening the serial port I got **System.IO.IOException** with this message Device or resource is busy.

After writing this piece of codes I got the exception.

```
    using (serialPort = new SerialPort(selectedSerialPort, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One))
    {
          if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
              serialPort.Open();

          //Do some stuff

          if (!serialPort.IsOpen)
              serialPort.Close();
    }
```

The exception occurred when I trying to open the serial port, on this line of code.

```
    serialPort.Open();
```

Comment: I think you'd better ask this question on Raspberry Pi stack forum:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: I add Raspberry PI tag in tags section, but I think it is a common problem and some part of it depends on dot net.